# Emulate a display in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: ubuntu, display, external-display, display-settings, video-capture

I am trying to create some explainer content on an Ubuntu 19.10 machine. I have an i5 4th gen processor and an AMD Radeon R7 graphics card in my hardware.

But I use an old monitor whose resolution is 1366x768, and use OBS Studio as my screen recording solution. I'm disappointed by the quality of video that I get, it's all blurry text and the videos are not even 720p.

I have tried xrandr to set a custom resolution to 1080p and expected the recording to be of 1080p quality, bit it wasn't.

I am almost out of options. Before I buy something I wanted to consider all possible software based solutions available to me.

I have explored the following

A display emulator
An external portable display

When I have had these conversations with my peers, they reply saying that a display makes no difference how it is rendered, and recording on a monitor/screen that is rendering 1080p content is not guaranteed to give me a 1080p screen record. I seek an opinion on if this is true. If not, then I would likely get myself a portable monitor, if that can give me good results.

Another concern people put across is screen size. One argument they have is since most mobile screens are anyway 1080p displays these days, I could use my mobile screen as a monitor and record it. But as the screen size is too small, when viewed on a desktop, I am guessing it will still be all blurry text.

If it happens to be true, how can I get the recording quality I desire? I'd like a 1080p video, or prefer 2k if possible. With the CPU and GPU I have, and from the specs on Intel website, my CPU can support displays up to 2k. How can I take full advantage of their capabilities?

I wanted to know if there is a software based solution I can try, like is there any way I can 'trick' my CPU to think there is a 1080p/2k display connected, and force it to output a 1080p/2k signal to a virtual device, which I can capture/route to some sort of a screen record?

The only advice I am hearing is to get a Mac as it is guaranteed to give me 4k recordings hassle free, but a Mac is way out of my budget.

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1: Removing links to the products as I cannot post more than 8 links.

Adding sample screens, and what dissatisfies me.

Normal recording at native resolution (1366x768)

1. OBS Settings: [Output](https://jmp.sh/B4NHwT9) and [video](https://jmp.sh/Qf2ErWq)
2. [Text video recording](https://jmp.sh/JzwGAhJ)
3. [Image video recording](https://jmp.sh/fsdSUYY)

I use the commands to set my resolution to scale to 1080p using xrandr as: `xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync` and `xrandr --addmode eDP-1 1920x1080_60.00`

1. OBS Settings: Same output, [video](https://jmp.sh/MueayO1)
2. [Text video recording](https://jmp.sh/ppIKttT)
3. [Image video recording](https://jmp.sh/kAN0vtm)

   Here are the originals of the images that I used: `https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/138818.jpg` and `https://www.hdcarwallpapers.com/walls/dragn_kaiser_3-HD.jpg` and `https://i.pinimg.com/originals/1f/87/90/1f8790df8b450fbf5c3b4a6b9db4f822.jpg`

My peers complain that it "looks" HD only on my screen because it was recorded on a custom resolution scaled to my monitor (15.6' native resolution being 1366x768), and that on any other size it would be a blurry content.

Comment: What kind of material do you want to record? Can you show freeze frames of your videos and tell us what is dissatisfactory? What OBS settings are you using (recording quality, output resolution).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft - made the edit to include the information you mentioned. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a better quality of image you can try to set bitrate to more higer value, like 5000 kbps or more.
Also I think that you can try to set CPU Usage preset to more slower preset. Like "quality" or "max.quality"

More higher bitrate will give you more load of internet, but also will give you more quality for your image. Big file (stream) size, but higher quality.
More slower profile of x264 processing will give you more load on your CPU, but it will have more time for processing and it will use more complex algorithms for processing video. Less file (stream) size, but higer quality.

Also you can find balance between this two parameters.

[OBS output settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXvBb.png)

Also can be helpful for you it's change FPS to 25-30, because for 60 fps bitrate should be higher, but for streaming "coding video tutorials" instead of "gaming videos" high fps doesn't need.

And you can try to set keyframe interval to 1 second and compare your result.